# ADC voltage divider calculation issue

Tags: adc

I want to measure the input voltage to my circuit. The input voltage is supposed to be anything between 0 to 36 V.
The voltage divider is simply a R1 = 100 kΩ on top and R2 = 10 kΩ on the bottom.
The ADC reference voltage of the controller is 3.3 V.
[image]

According to my calculation,

1. When I’m calculating the RAW value to the input voltage value by using the below formula, the calculated voltage value is not matching with the input voltage. There is tolerance. You can find the voltage values in the report below, highlighted in red.

[image]

2. The formula for converting the raw value to the input voltage value is:
   ((Raw·ADC_Ref)/(4096))·(R1+R2)/(R2)
3. When I’m calculating the raw value to the voltage divider value, there is no issue. Here the calculated value is matching with the measured value, highlighted in blue.
4. In the microcontroller datasheet, there is a mention of an internal series resistor which is connected internally; please refer the image below. ADC input connected to the ADC. So, the internal resistor of 6.9 kΩ is added.

[image]

5. Can you please let me know how I should add this internal resistor to the formula? Or is there any other issue in this circuit or our calculation?

Comment: If the input voltage is 0V, according to your table, can you explain why the voltage after the voltage divider is 0.53V?

Comment: Have you accounted for leakage in the protection diodes shown? Also, have you allowed sufficient acquisition time when sampling?

Comment: That's rather a large voltage with no input. It's suspiciously close to what would be expected from the weak pullup current, which should be disabled on an analog input. Is it possible the input has been damaged in your experimentation?

Comment: The easy solution would be to feed the 100k/10k signal into a voltage follower, and that output into the MCU ADC input. This way you don't have to take account of the various tolerances which significantly influences your ADC value.

Comment: @Unimportant Thanks for the reply. Looks 0.53V during 0V at input causing the issue looks like. I tried removing D4 diode in the circuit, but Still, I'm getting 0.53V. Same circuit I have tried by connecting ADC input to CPU-i.MX6ULL (with D4 DNP). here I'm getting proper 0V when input voltage is 0V. What could be the reason for 0.53V?

Comment: @PStechPaul Acquisition time given is 5Second. I have not accounted Leakage in the protection because I have removed the diode and tried. Issue remains same, getting 0.53v during 0V at input. what could be the reason for getting 0.53V at resistor devider?

Comment: Edited Main post (Circuit diagram). ADC input is connected to ADCy, not ADCx.In my design ADCx is not configured as ADC, its configured as GPIO.

Comment: If you can, use 10k/1k resistors. If not, use a "correction" formula with calibrated divider.

Comment: What kind of DAC is connected to ADCy?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany makes a good point about internal pull-up resistors.  If the pin is multi-purpose, make sure that any pull on the pin is turned off.  I've seen cases where an MCU user manual states that the digital pull-up needs to be disabled even when you are using a pin as an analog input rather than as digital I/O.

Comment: @Antonio51 Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried with 10K/1K divider value and it works, Here I'm getting 0V during the input 0V. Still a 1v difference between the input voltage and the calculated one. What could be the issue with 100K/10K?

Comment: I think that the Thevenin resistance of the voltage divider must be lower than the internal impedance of ADC input. Perhaps also that there can be an "input" current offset. What microcontroller?

Comment: Don't understand why ADCx and ADCy can be "independent" inputs when they are wired through R1?

Comment: @Antonio51 LPC804 micro-controller been used in the design

Comment: Perhaps some answer in this manual? https://edit.wpgdadawant.com/uploads/news_file/program/2020/35916/tech_files/UM11065_LPC804_User_manual.pdf  **9.4.5 Analog mode**
The switch matrix automatically configures the pin in analog mode whenever an analog input or output is selected as the pin’s function. In analog mode, the internal pull-up must be disabled via the IOCON register. ?

Comment: EE&O  it seems that for ADC_0, there are two pins used ... PIO0_1 and PIO0_7 (pages 97 and 98) ???

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a current feed out of the ADC input. It behaves not pure resistive, more like roughly estimated 51 kohm parallel to a constant current source of around 4.3 µA. This is typical for a chip internal pullup resistor built out of special semiconductor strutures. This pullup resistor must be disabled.

If this has been done already, another reason could be an ESD damage at the internal protection diode.

**Edit:**
After reading the MCU datasheet, I assume you use the ADC function inside the capacitive touch sensing feature of this MCU. This can indeed measure voltages, but has capacitor charging hardware around it.

Simply don't use it that way. Use the "normal" ADC interface instead.

Comment: I have tried disabling the internal pull-up in the ADC pin. Still, the issue remains the same.

Comment: @Chitharanjan Please specify the MCU you are using for better analysis

Comment: LPC804 micro-controller used